# Importing 14 digit timestamp from CSV to MySQL and avoid stripping out data

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm creating a mySQL db that will contain as part of its data, timestamps.  These timestamps will be imported from a CSV file in which they appear like this - 20110701083231

My question is which is the best datatype to store these as?

In my attempts so far, during the import process (which I am doing via PHPMyAdmin) the end of the timestamp appears to get stripped out and they become 2011070000000.

Oddly, when I return to the CSV file, the entries there also appeared to be stripped out in the same way...?

Thanks in advance for any light you shed and for all previous help given.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what you did exactly. With what datatypes have you tried it?

Comment: @tombom, Fair point.  I have just tried with a test file - it contains 20110701090833 repeated across 3 fields.  I have a matching table in mysql to receive it.  The first field is a varchar (20), the second a datetime and the third a bigint (20).  After import the first column contains '2.01107E+13', the second '2002-01-10 07:00:00' and the third '20110700000000'.   On reopening the CSV file it now contains 20110700000000 in every field...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try with this statement?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'yourFile.csv'
INTO TABLE yourTable
(@var1)
SET theColumnWhereItShouldBe = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%Y%m%d%H%i%s');
```

Oh, and the column should be of type `datetime` or `timestamp`.

Comment: Thanks.  Just tried this into two different fields - one a datetime and one a timestamp.  The datetime contains a nicely formatted 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and the timestamp the current date and time.

Comment: You mean it worked for timestamp? Still strange then, that it doesn't work for datetime.

Comment: UPDATE - success (I think).  I tried formatting the field in the CSV file in excel to a number field away from the general field it was, and this in combination of your code above has uploaded the right dates and times to the datetime type column.  It seems a shame to have to reformat the CSV file though...

Comment: in reply to our question - it DIDNT work for timestamp either, it just showed the date and time of me uploading ie now.

Comment: @highfidelity Glad to hear it worked, though the reformatting shouldn't be needed. There's still something strange. Maybe this link can help you further: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date Anyway, feel free to accept my answer or ask away if I can help you more.

Comment: Upvoted, but do replace '%h' with '%H'. '%h' is 00..12, while '%H' is 00..23

Comment: @ShlomiNoach Thanks, was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Save them as in the `datetime` format. That means you will need to do some formatting of those values before saving them but that isn't difficult to do:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("YmdHis", "20110701083231");
$date = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I am currently importing via PHPmyadmin, so I do not have options to format as part of the import - do I?  In which case, should I switch to importing via a custom built php page in which I could, I assume, use your code above?