# INFILE MySQL - TIMESTAMP not working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use the INFILE statement to import data from a tab delimited file. However, one of the data types is a TIMESTAMP. I tried using NULL in the flat file, but the resulting value after executing the statement was '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. What value can I use so the TIMESTAMP will work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260360/importing-14-digit-timestamp-from-csv-to-mysql-and-avoid-stripping-out-data

Comment: what is the format of your timestamp in your tab delimited file?

Comment: @duffy356 - It does not have a format. I though if I did not pass it a value, the column would automatically generate the time of insertion. Hence why I tried NULL. I suppose I could identify the fields by column name and just omit the TIMESTAMP column. I was just hoping there would be an easier way. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

your table definition should be

```
timestamp_column TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

then when inserting the timestamp_column should be time of insert.